# WPF create UIElement from code for styles - VirtualCanvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, mvvm

I have a nice working application with many objects shown in Canvas (FULL MVVM). I'd like to be able in a new use case to deal with 200 000 objects shown (only 100 shown, the other ones elsewhere using scrollbars). So I can't escape to use GUI Virtualisation. But there is no easy way to apply it for a canvas with different objects at different places / sizes. Isn't it ? :)

**This is what I have today :**

- I use basic style declaration like this for each kind of objects (in resource dictionaries) :

```
<!-- Basic sample ControlTemplate -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ActionTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Border Style="{StaticResource MouseOverStyle}" Width="20" Height="20" Background="Pink" />
</ControlTemplate>

<!-- Style declaration, using two styles together -->
<Style x:Key="ActionStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ActionTemplate}" />
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CtxMenu}" />
</Style>

<!-- Template declaration refering to the defined style -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:ViewModelAction}">
     <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ActionStyle}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

- I created a basic ItemsControl filled with ViewModels objects :

  ```
  <ItemsControl x:Name="dataObjects" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ViewData}">
  ```

Each time I add a VM in ViewData, the datatemplate search for style which get the control template for the rendering.
That was working nice but if I want to be able to use the VirtualCanvas sample ([Sample from Microsoft here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jgoldb/2008/03/09/virtualized-wpf-canvas/)), I need to be able to build objects from code... How may I create the UIElement instance ? (remember I don't want the GUI to build all objects, I want them to be created when needed by code)

**This is what I should have tomorrow : (any other solution ?) when UI element has to be shown, I have to create it :**

UIElement elmt = ???

I'm stucked, thank you for your help / advice / solution / ... ;o)

Comment: "f I want to be able to use the VirtualCanvas sample, I need to be able to build objects from code" why? if use `VirtualCanvas` panel as ItemsPanel, everything else shouldn't change

Comment: I do use it but the VirtualCanvas implementation has constraints. The objects shown in the canvas must implement a build method which returns an UIElement instance when it has to be shown.

Comment: @MartinDupond `VirtualCanvas` uses `VirtualChildren` property which can be assigned to. But for this control, all your objects should implement `IVirtualChild` interface, which could be problematic.

Comment: Right. Does it help if I say I am able to easily instanciate UserControl. I wonder if I can't do the same stuff with Styles definition :). It would not be easy and fast to implement but it would be possible. It's a pity Canvas in Framework is not able to manage itself a huge MV collection by showing only necessary.